# Trivial homomorphism from a non-abelian group to an abelian group

Tags: nt.number-theory, gr.group-theory, modular-forms

I am stuck on this problem and cannot seem to find a good reasoning for drawing the required conclusion. The problem is as follows:

Let $m\in \mathbb{N}$ and $n>3$. I want to show that there can be no non-trivial homomorphism between $\operatorname{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})\to \mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$. Additionally, find all homomorphisms when $n=2$ and $n=3$.

Here is what I have so far. Suppose $\phi$ is such a homomorphism.
One can check that
\begin{equation*}S=\begin{pmatrix}
1&0\\
1&1
\end{pmatrix} \text{ and }
T= \begin{pmatrix}
1&1\\
0&1
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}  generates $\operatorname{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})$ and both $S$ and $T$ are of order $n$. It looks like I have to end up using the fact that $\phi$ is a homomorphism from a non-abelian group to an abelian group, i.e., the commutator $S^{-1}T^{-1}ST$ potentially plays some role, but I am not sure what that is.

Comment: Where did you encounter this problem?  If it is an exercise, then it is probably not appropriate for MO, but might do better on [MSE](http://math.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @LSpice I had posted it on MSE but no one able to provide me with any pertinent suggestion. This was an exercise problem but not for a course I was in. I found it in a book on modular forms which was used in a course in 2021.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

$SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ is generated by $U=\left(\begin{smallmatrix}0&1\\-1&1\end{smallmatrix}\right)$ of order $6$ and $V=\left(\begin{smallmatrix}0&1\\-1&0\end{smallmatrix}\right)$ of order $4$, subject only to the relations $U^3=V^2$, $V^4=1$. In other words, it's an amalgamated free product of cyclic groups of order $6$ and $4$. The abelianisation is therefore $\mathbb{Z}/12\mathbb{Z}$ with generator $UV=\left(\begin{smallmatrix}-1&0\\-1&-1\end{smallmatrix}\right)$. The only extra relation you need for the abelianisation of $SL_2(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})$ is $(UV)^n=1$ if $n$ is even and $(UV)^n=V^2$ if $n$ is odd. This determines the homomorphisms to any abelian group.

So for example if $n=12$ then the abelianisation is exactly $\mathbb{Z}/12\mathbb{Z}$, contradicting your assertion about $n>3$.

Comment: In case you doubt this, try the following Magma commands: R:=ResidueClassRing(12); G:=SL(2,R); H:=CommutatorSubgroup(G); A:=quo<G|H>; A; The result is "Permutation group A acting on a set of cardinality 12, Order = 12 = 2^2 * 3. IsCyclic(A); gives true.

Comment: You implicitly use the surjectivity of the map $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbf{Z})\to\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbf{Z}/m\mathbf{Z})$, which indeed holds because the latter is generated by elementary matrices.

Comment: @YCor Yes, the said map is indeed surjective, with the modular group $\Gamma(m)$, as the kernel.

Comment: Very nice answer!  Do you have a reference for the fact in the first sentence (or a comment-length proof)?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_group#Presenting_as_a_matrix_group

Comment: I'm a little surprised by the assertion about "the only extra relation you need for $SL_2(\mathbb{Z}/n)$ is...". I've seen presentations in the literature for $SL_2(\mathbb{Z}/n)$ in terms of $U, V$, and even used them in my own work, but they've always been substantially more complicated than that one -- see e.g. page 2 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/1307.0625.pdf. That doesn't *per se* mean that your statement is false, but it makes me curious to see a proof.

Comment: No, I'm only claiming that that's all that's necessary for the abelianisation. It certainly doesn't give a presentation for $SL_2(\mathbb{Z}/n)$!

Comment: OK, I see now that you are not claiming this, but then how is the assertion proved?

Comment: Well, to show that no further relations are necessary, you only really need compute in $SL_2(\mathbb{Z}/12\mathbb{Z})$, which is what my first comment above was about.

Comment: I don't understand: how does computing in $SL_2(\mathbb{Z} / 12)$ show that no further relations are needed to compute the abelianisation for $n \ne 12$?

Comment: Let $m$ be the greatest common divisor of $n$ and $12$, and compare both with $SL_2(\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z})$.

Comment: I just want to point out that this answer is somewhat overcomplicated. You don’t need to know that it’s an amalgamated free product, just that $U$ and $V$ generate, and satisfy the given relation.

Answer (score 11):

To complement Dave Benson's answer, here is how you can check that if $n$ is coprime to $6$, there are no such homomorphisms. Letting $A:=\begin{pmatrix}2\\&2^{-1}\end{pmatrix}$, we have $[A^{-1},S]=\begin{pmatrix}1\\3&1\end{pmatrix}$ and $[A,T]=\begin{pmatrix}1&3\\&1\end{pmatrix}$, and $3\in\mathbb Z/n$ generates, so we are done.

Comment: If you are using the same $S$ and $T$ as in the question, then I am getting a different commutator than yours.

Comment: @ShyamalSayak sorry, I mixed up your $S$ and $T$. Now it should be correct.